# Can't delete reported post

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I made a plugin for report posts on WordPress, the report post input was successful. but when I tried to delete the report post data on the admin page it didn't work. sorry if my english is bad.

[image]

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Report Post Plugin
Description: This plugin adds a report post feature and a view reported posts admin page.
Version: 1.0
Author: Anonim
*/

// Create the reported_posts table
function create_reported_posts_table() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'reported_posts';

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        flag_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        video_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
        flag_message text,
        reported_at datetime NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_reported_posts_table');

// Hook to deactivate the plugin and perform cleanup
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'deactivate_plugin_function');

function deactivate_plugin_function() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'reported_posts';

    // Drop the table if it exists
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name");
}

// Register uninstall hook
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'delete_reported_posts_table');

// Function to delete the reported_posts table
function delete_reported_posts_table() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'reported_posts';

    // Delete the table if it exists
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name");
}

// Enqueue JavaScript for admin
function enqueue_report_post_js_admin() {
    wp_enqueue_script('report-post-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/report-post.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    // Define and localize variables for JavaScript
    $report_post_vars = array(
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('report_post_nonce'),
    );
    wp_localize_script('report-post-js', 'report_post_vars', $report_post_vars);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_report_post_js_admin');

// Add a menu item in the admin panel
function create_report_post_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Reported Posts',
        'Reported Posts',
        'manage_options',
        'report_post_viewer',
        'report_post_page'
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'create_report_post_menu');

// Callback function to display the reported post data
function report_post_page() {
    // Check user capability (you can modify this based on your needs)
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        wp_die('Access Denied');
    }

    // Include WordPress database access
    global $wpdb;

    // Define the table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'reported_posts';

    // Retrieve the reported post data
    $reported_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

    // Display the data in a table
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h2>Reported Posts</h2>';
    echo '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Flag ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Video ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Flag Message</th>';
    echo '<th>Reported At</th>';
    echo '<th>Actions</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';

    foreach ($reported_posts as $post) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . esc_html($post->id) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . esc_html($post->flag_id) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . esc_html($post->video_id) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . esc_html($post->flag_message) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . esc_html($post->reported_at) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<a href="#" class="delete-post" data-post-id="' . esc_attr($post->id) . '">Delete</a>';
        echo ' | ';
        echo '<a href="' . get_edit_post_link($post->video_id) . '">Edit</a>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
}

// AJAX handler for deleting reported data
add_action('wp_ajax_delete_reported_data', 'delete_reported_data_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_reported_data', 'delete_reported_data_callback'); // Handle for non-logged-in users

function delete_reported_data_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('report_post_nonce', 'nonce');

    // Get the post ID from the AJAX request
    $post_id = isset($_POST['post_id']) ? intval($_POST['post_id']) : 0;

    // Check user permissions or any other validation
    if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'reported_posts';

        // Delete data from the reported_posts table based on ID
        $result = $wpdb->delete($table_name, array('id' => $post_id));

        if ($result !== false) {
            wp_send_json_success(array('message' => 'Data deleted successfully.'));
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Failed to delete data.'));
        }
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Access denied.'));
    }
}

// Hook to handle form submission
add_action('init', 'process_report_form');

function process_report_form() {
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'flag') {
        // Sanitize and validate form data
        $flag_id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['flag_id']);
        $video_id = intval($_POST['video_id']);
        $flag_message = sanitize_text_field($_POST['flag_message']);

        // Insert data into the database
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'reported_posts';

        $data = array(
            'flag_id' => $flag_id,
            'video_id' => $video_id,
            'flag_message' => $flag_message,
            'reported_at' => current_time('mysql'),
        );

        $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);

        // Display a success message
        echo '<div class="success">Thank you! We appreciate your help.</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

this is `report-post.js`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Handler for deleting reported posts
    $('.delete-post').on('click', function() {
        var postId = $(this).data('post-id');

        // Confirm the deletion
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this data?')) {
            // AJAX request to delete the reported data
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'delete_reported_data', // Action to delete data
                    nonce: report_post_vars.nonce,
                    post_id: postId // Send the post ID to be deleted
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        // Remove the deleted data row from the table
                        $('tr[data-post-id="' + postId + '"]').remove();
                        alert(response.data.message);
                    } else {
                        alert('Failed to delete data: ' + response.data.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert('Failed to delete data.');
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: there's a little confusion, the new table you created has an `id` primary key that auto-increments, aka the report ID, but your AJAX callbacks refer to it as a post ID. Is this callback meant to delete the report, or is it meant to delete the post that the report is about? I also notice you use the global `$wpdb` value but there is no declaration that you intend to use it, aka `global $wpdb;` in the `delete_reported_data_callback` function, are you sure this is intended? I also saw you chose not to use the modern REST APIs for AJAX and instead used the old legacy `admin-ajax.php`

Comment: I want to delete the existing field in the reported_posts table

Comment: and when `$wpdb->delete` returns false have you attempted to grab the error message from the `wpdb` object? That would give you the answer for why this happens. Additionally, instead of reporting that the deletion failed, report that the deletion of XYZ failed. That way if the ID was lost somewhere or it was the wrong ID then you'd be able to see that in the error message returned, e.g `'Failed to delete data: ' . $post_id` is more useful. It would for example tell us if `var postId = $(this).data('post-id');` failed by showing us a null or empty value for post ID

Comment: Similarly the AJAX handler tests if the post ID is set, and if it isn't set it gives it the value `0` but that's a failure state, you can't delete the 0th  record but it attempts it anyway. Shouldn't it see that it's `0` and exit early with an error message? Sanitisation has been performed but no validation is happening in the code